# Http file download problem with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7

I'm having a virtual directory that holds videos of format MP4. My problem is that i'm not able to access some of the "mp4" file via http. But i can browse and play the file through the shared folder not via http. I added the MIME extension for MP4 also. Please find the event log as below

### Log

**Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e023cf, faulting module MSVCR80.dll, version 8.0.50727.4016, time stamp 0x49cc5361, exception code 0xc000000d, fault offset 0x00004e12, process id 0x2edc, application start time 0x01cb598243012abd.**

Also in fiddler i'm getting the log as **ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding mime type in this way. I have done this and didn't get any error.

```
File name extension : .mp4
MIME Type : audio/mpeg
```

Comment: Yes sure, there is nothing wrong in adding video/mpeg. I also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I happened accross this while trying to solve a simular bug

Using IIS7 to be able to download the files I had to add the
.mp4 video/mpeg MIME Type to the Server..

This allowed the download of the File, but upon playing it would always fail.
I noticed that if you "save as" it would change the Filename to a .mpeg file which the player didn't reconise as the filetype when trying to play..

To solve I changed the MIME to
**.mp4 video/mp4**

and it seems to work now (not sure if this breaks anything but it worked in a local intranet for me)

CooPzZ